# jar file for StreamedContent in java

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jar

I want to retrieve file from db and display it in datatable in primefaces.
I want to use this code:

```
public StreamedContent convertFichier(byte[] bytes) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    System.out.println("size file : " + bytes.length);
    StreamedContent image = new DefaultStreamedContent(is);
    System.out.println("dans le convertisseur : " + image.getContentType());
    return image;
}
```

But I don't know what jar file is used for `StreamedContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this page and jar file

http://www.primefaces.org/downloads

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/primefaces/primefaces/5.3/primefaces-5.3.jar

StreamedContent located in this package inside jar above

```
org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent
```

You can also download jar with sources from Community download block on page which I specified earlier.

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/primefaces/primefaces/5.3/primefaces-5.3-sources.jar

Comment: 3.0M3??? Why??? you should already have a PrimeFaces jar anyway if you are using PrimeFaces. Very weird question and please use a newer version